# Celery + Fask-Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, celery

How do you use the `db` object and its `session` attribute within a celery task?
Should I call `db.session.remove` at the end of the task? The db object is instantiated as `db = SQLAlchemy(app)`

The file that defines the tasks is structured like that:

```
from project import celery, db, app
from project.models import Model

@celery.task()
def task_1():
    model = Model.query.get(0)
    model.arg = 1
    db.session.commit()
```

If the concurrency is set to 1, everything works as expected. 
If the `--maxtaskperchild` argument is specified, that task starts throwing: “MySQL server has gone away” errors as soon as the `--maxtaskperchild` is hit (i.e, a second process is started in place of the first one).

However, if I don't specify `maxtasksperchild`, I don't have errors anymore.

What is the best practice to handle session within a celery task?